# Flutter Hot Load is unuseful,why?

Tags: flutter

`Performing hot reload...
Syncing files to device Android SDK built for x86 64...
Reloaded 0 of 537 libraries in 2,353ms.`

I just change a text or the width of a Container, but after I use Hot Load, nothing has changed. Can anyone help me?

Comment: This would require more details. What was the original code? What did you change? What result did you expect after hot-reload?

Comment: There are a few limitations what hot-reload can't do https://flutter.io/docs/development/tools/hot-reload#limitations